# Pass a lazy translation string including variable to function in Django

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, lazy-evaluation

Inside a Django view, I create a subject like that:

```
subject = _(u"%(user)s has posted a comment") % { 'user': user }
```

Then I pass this subject to a function, which handles email notifications:

```
send_notifications(request, subject, url)
```

In send_notifications, I iterate over all subscriptions and send emails. However, each user can have a different language, so I activate the user's language dynamically via Django's activate:

```
def send_notifications(request, subject, url):
    from django.utils.translation import activate
    for s in Subscription.objects.filter(url=url):
        activate(s.user.userprofile.lang)
        send_mail(subject, render_to_string('notification_email.txt', locals()), settings.SERVER_EMAIL, [s.user.email])
```

The template gets rendered in the correct language of each user. However, the subject is passed as an evaluated and translated string to send_notifications and thus, is not translated.

I played around with lazy translations and lambda functions as parameters, but without success. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the translated subject, just pass it non translated:

```
subject = '%(user)s has posted a comment'
context = {'user': user}

def send_notifications(request, subject, url, context):
    from django.utils.translation import activate
    for s in Subscription.objects.filter(url=url):
        activate(s.user.userprofile.lang)
        send_mail(_(subject) % context, render_to_string('notification_email.txt', locals()), settings.SERVER_EMAIL, [s.user.email])
```

If you're not going to personalize the contents per user, then you might as well limit the number of renderings because that's a little confusing:

```
# also do your imports at the top to catch import issues early
from django.utils.translation import activate
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

def send_notifications(request, url, 
    translatable_subject, context,
    body_template='notification_template.txt'):
    previous_lang = None
    for s in Subscription.objects.filter(url=url).order_by('user__userprofile__lang'):
        if s.user.userprofile.lang != previous_lang:
            activate(s.user.userprofile.lang)
            subject = _(translatable_subject) % context
            body = render_to_string(body_template, locals())
        send_mail(subject, body, settings.SERVER_EMAIL, [s.user.email])
        previous_lang = s.user.userprofile.lang
```

As such, it is much more obvious that you're not going to render emails per usage.

This slight rewrite should make you doubt about the original choice of a couple of names (locals, notification_template).

The above sample code is barely an "educated guess" and you should double check it and make sure you understand everything before you paste it.

Comment: Thanks jpic. It's a really good answer - just voted up! However, the problem is: send_notification doesn't know about the user variable used in the subject - it's a very generic notification function. So I can't access that 'user' object in the subject template :-P

Comment: Oh, very cool addition to your original answer! Thanks! I didn't get a notification about the change and stumbled upon it just now by chance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution myself. In case anybody runs into a similar problem:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

# create subject as raw string in Django view
raw_subject = r"%(username)s has posted a comment"

# for the sake of generic variables, create a dictionary to pass to function
extra_context = { 'user': user }

# call function with raw string and dictionary as params
send_notifications(request, raw_subject, url, extra_context)

# translate the raw string inside send_notifications into the temporarily activated language
translated_subject = _(raw_subject) % extra_context
```

Appears to be working as desired :) Since we are working with several different notifications, I tried to avoid an extra template for each kind. However, calling a template with extra_context is also a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a class that will handle the translation, passing the context of the string to this class.

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Translatable(object):
    def __init__(self, text, context):
        self.text = text
        self.context = context

    def __str__(self):
        return _(self.text).format(**self.context)
```

In your function, just call `str(subject)`:

```
def send_notifications(request, subject, url):
    from django.utils.translation import activate
    for s in Subscription.objects.filter(url=url):
        activate(s.user.userprofile.lang)
        send_mail(str(subject), render_to_string('notification_email.txt', locals()), settings.SERVER_EMAIL, [s.user.email])
```

And passes subject to your function as following:

```
subject = Translatable(_("{user} has posted a comment"), context={'user': user})
send_notifications(request, subject, url)
```